# Call function the moment before script crashes?

Tags: python, crash, crash-reports

I am solving the following problem:

I have a script which should be running as a service 24/7. Because it is quite important, I would like it to send me an email in case it crashes. I found [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module, but the docs specifically says it cannot handle crashes.

So my question is: is there any better way of achieving this than by running another serivce which will be checking if this one is running? Or the goal here is to write the service so that it cannot crash (which is almost impossible)?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: How crash-y is this crash? Are we talking unhandled exceptions here, or something like a segfault? `atexit` exit handlers will still run in the case of an unhandled exception.

Comment: You cannot handle all types of crashes, as some of them are "uncatchable" like mentioned segfault, or `SIGTERM`. What you can do is to use external tool like [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html) which will handle starting/restarting for you and using it's [events](http://supervisord.org/events.html) you may listen for example for processes entering `FATAL` state to send an e-mail. Embedding mechanisms to monitor process into same process is risky.

Comment: I will look at the supervisor tool, it seems that it is the only correct aproach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I mean to do what you ask in the first part just wrap the main part of the script with a try/except.

myscript.py:

```
def main():
   long_running_process()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
       main()
   except:
       send_email()
```

Comment: In case of a segmentation fault, this has no chance to work.

Comment: yea then like said above you need some service monitor like supervisor, upstart, init.d etc..

Answer (score 0):

You could use makefile.. and have two targets first one would run your script and second one would send an email that script stopped executing..

```
.PHONY: all run_script send_email clean

all: run_script send_email 

run_script:
    @echo "Run my script"
    python myscript.py

send_email:
    @echo "Sending an email"
    python send_email.py 

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up..."
    rm *.txt
```

Save that in makefile.
Run with just make or make all